# Get start of Previous Month from Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the start of the previous month from sunday.
For ex : today is 18 June 2021. I want to get the previous month date starting from Sunday. i.e 2 May 2021(falls on sunday). I want to keep it dynamic so that it takes the first day of the previous month from Sunday onwards.

I have written the query to get the previous month. But don't know how to get the first sunday of the previous month.

```
select dateadd(mm, -2,dateadd(dd, +1, eomonth(getdate()))) as FirstDayOfPrevMonth
```

Comment: Invest in a calendar table, then this is trivial.

Comment: `dateadd(mm,` How much effort do you save by typing "mm" vs. typing "month"? Which is more easily understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using EOMONTH, by going two months back and adding days till sunday of next month.

```sql
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY,8-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
    ,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AS FirstSunday_ofThePreviousMonth
```

| FirstSunday_ofThePreviousMonth |
| --- |
| 2021-05-02 |

**Note**: Here, we are assuming that Sunday will be 7 (as per US_English language settings). Datefirst will be 7, for US_English language setting. If it is different language setting, the subtraction value has to be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bunch of date manipulations and arithmetic.  But assuming that your setting are such that "Sunday" is day 1, you can use:

```
select v.*, 
       dateadd(day, (8 - datepart(weekday, v2.prev_month)) % 7, v2.prev_month) as first_sunday_prev_month
from (values (convert(date, '2021-06-18')),
             (convert(date, '2021-09-18')),
             (convert(date, '2021-05-18')),
             (convert(date, '2021-04-18'))
     ) v(dte) cross apply
     (values (dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(v.dte), v.dte)) )) v2(prev_month)
```